# Continuous bijection from $\mathbb R-\{0\}$ to $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

I know such a function exists if continuity is not required.

How do you prove it doesn't exist when continuity is required?

For the sake of completeness,  note that a continuous bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R-{0}$ cannot exist either (the IVT applies trivially).

Comment: What are $R$ and $R^*$?

Comment: A continuous injection $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an embedding (a homeomorphism to the image). Since $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that a continuous injection cannot be surjective.

Comment: @DanielFischer Being a homeomorphism is more than being a continuous bijection. E.g. $[0,1)$ bijects continuously onto $S^1$.

Comment: @Christoph But here we're dealing with open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, that implies that every continuous injection is an open map (in dimension $1$, a consequence of the intermediate value theorem; it holds for continuous injections $f\colon U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ where $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, but for $n > 1$, it's much deeper [invariance of domain]), hence a homeomorphism to the image.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for elaborating on that!

Comment: @Daniel I wanted to "catch" you on the implication (injection implies embedding), then I realized that it works in this case. Thanks a lot for pointing at the general theorem (invariance of domain). I probably heard about it before, but apparently it didn't quite sink in back then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assume $f: \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous bijection. Denote $\mathbb{R}_{>0} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x > 0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{<0} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x < 0\}$.

1. Spaces $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{<0}$ are connected and $f$ is continuous, therefore $f(\mathbb{R}_{>0})$ and $f(\mathbb{R}_{>0})$ are also connected. Since $f$ is a bijection, we see that $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of two *disjoint* non-empty connected subsets: $\mathbb{R} = f(\mathbb{R}_{<0}) \cup f(\mathbb{R}_{>0})$.
2. Connected subsets in $\mathbb{R}$ are precisely the same thing as [intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29). It's easy to see then that one of the two sets $f(\mathbb{R}_{<0})$ and $f(\mathbb{R}_{>0})$ must be unbounded on one side and closed on the other side. For instance, let's assume that $f(\mathbb{R}_{>0}) = [y, +\infty)$, where $y \in \mathbb{R}$. (The other possible cases are analogous).
3. Let $x = f^{-1}(y)$. The restricted function $f|_{\mathbb{R}_{>0}}$ reaches its minimum at point $x > 0$. It follows that there are $x_1$ and $x_2$ somewhere close to $x$ such that $0 < x_1 < x < x_2$, $f(x_1) > f(x)$ and $f(x_2) > f(x)$. Now it's easy to reach a contradiction with the injectivity of $f$ using the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). Done.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slight variation on Dan's excellent answer.

Note that a continuous bijection between two connected sets whose topology is an order topology are either order preserving or order reversing. But it has to be either an order isomorphism or an anti-isomorphism (order reversing).

Assume by contradiction that there is such $f$. As Dan points out, the image of $\Bbb R_{>0}$ and $\Bbb R_{<0}$ are both intervals, which are disjoint and whose union is $\Bbb R$. Therefore one has the form $[x,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,x]$.

In either case this means that the restriction of $f$ to one of the two connected parts is not an order isomorphism (or anti-isomorphism), since neither parts has endpoints but one of the parts is mapped to an interval with an endpoint.

Answer (score -2):

The topology is different. $\mathbb{R}=(-\infty,\infty)$ has two open ends and $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}=(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ has four. Continuous functions map boundaries to boundaries, which cannot happen bijectively. For instance, $\log |x|$ is an example that maps two-to-one.

Continuous bijection only exists between spaces with equal topology.

Comment: Continuous bijections can exist between spaces with different topology. Such a bijection can have a non-continuous inverse.

Comment: Is this still a "continuous bijection"? I assumed that by "continuous" the OP means continuity in both directions.

Comment: I doubt that that's what he meant. People do talk about continuous bijections without implying homeomorphisms.